# Jsoup parece nao estar a funcionar

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Ola tenho este bocado de código que da um link e que vai a net com o jsoup tira alguma informação e depois mete essa informação numa ArrayList usada numa ListView. Mas o problema é que não sei porque a Array cursos não fica cheia , o site muda consoante a letra no url por isso e que faço este código . Não percebo porque e que ele não enche a variável cursos das .lin-area-c2 que estão no site. 
Aqui esta o código :

```
  public class Chose_curso extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView pickLetraText;
private ListView cursoList;
private Spinner letraPicker;

private ArrayList<String> letras = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> cursos = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chose_curso);


    pickLetraText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pickLetraText);
    cursoList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cursoList);
    letraPicker = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.letraPicker);

    letras.add("A");
    letras.add("B");
    letras.add("C");
    letras.add("D");
    letras.add("E");
    letras.add("F");
    letras.add("G");
    letras.add("H");
    letras.add("I");
    letras.add("J");
    letras.add("L");
    letras.add("M");
    letras.add("N");
    letras.add("O");
    letras.add("P");
    letras.add("Q");
    letras.add("R");
    letras.add("S");
    letras.add("T");
    letras.add("U");
    letras.add("V");




    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterLetras = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Chose_curso.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,letras);

    adapterLetras.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    letraPicker.setAdapter(
            new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                    adapterLetras,
                    R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected,
                    // R.layout.contact_spinner_nothing_selected_dropdown, // Optional
                    this));

    Document document = null;



    letraPicker.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            setCursoList();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }


        });}


public void setCursoList(){
            try  {
                if(letraPicker.getSelectedItem()!=null){
                    cursos.clear();
                    Document document = null;

                    String site ="http://www.dges.gov.pt/guias/indcurso.asp?letra="+(letraPicker.getSelectedItem().toString());

                    document = Jsoup.connect(site).get();
                    for(int contador=0;contador<document.select(".lin-area-c2").size();contador++){
                        cursos.add(String.valueOf((document.select(".lin-area-c2").get(contador).text())));}}
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }






    ArrayAdapter<String> cursosAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Chose_curso.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,cursos);

    cursoList.setAdapter(cursosAdapter);


}
```

}

Link do site http://www.dges.gov.pt/guias/indcurso.asp?letra=B neste caso com a letra B selecionada . O que eu estou a fazer e basicamente dar ao user a oportunidade de escolher qual letra e que eles querem no url quando vou buscar a informação!

Para resolver fiz desta maneira como me indicado :

```
  public List<String> buscarCursos(final String letra) throws IOException {

    final List<String> cursos1 = new ArrayList<>();

    final ArrayAdapter<String> cursosAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Chose_curso.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,cursos1);

    cursoList.setAdapter(cursosAdapter);

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try  {
                String site = "http://www.dges.gov.pt/guias/indcurso.asp?letra=";
                Document document;

                Elements lista;

                document = Jsoup.connect(site +letra).get();

                lista = document.select(".lin-area-c2");

                for (Element elemento: lista) {
                    cursos1.add(elemento.text());
                }



            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();


    return cursos1;

}
```

Usei o buscar cursos para retirar todos os cursos para cada letra como a resposta que me foi indicada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte método para buscar todas as descrições de cursos:

```
public List<String> buscarCursos(String letra) throws IOException {
  String site = "http://www.dges.gov.pt/guias/indcurso.asp?letra=";
  List<String> cursos = new ArrayList<>();
  Document document;

  Elements lista;

  document = Jsoup.connect(site + letra).get();

  lista = document.select(".lin-area-c2");

  for (Element elemento: lista) {
    cursos.add(elemento.text());
  }

  return cursos;
}
```

Comment: Fiz como estavas a dizer mas como me estava so a dar o erro android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException tive que meter um thread , fiz Log.d(tag,buscarCursos(letraPicker.getSelectedItem.toString())) e deu me return de uma ArrayList vazia

Comment: Fiz thread.start

Comment: Dei upVote pelo seu tempo , se me conseguisse ajudar com a informação que lhe dei ficaria muito agradecido

Comment: Ja fiz com que funciona-se obrigado

Comment: @EmanuelSobreiro conte-nos como resolveu

Comment: Ja fiz mas tenho um problema , quando seleciono a letra aquilo não faz upgrade , so faz quando eu clico nessa letra duas vezes seguidas